# Rename assets in Release from GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, release

I have a `pre-release` on my repository with assets that have a naming scheme like:
`my-assets-rc.jar`

Once I change the release state from `pre-release` to `release`, I would like to remove the `rc` suffix from the assets, hence renaming assets.

I know you can do this manually when editing the release, but is it possible to do this easily automatically with GitHub Actions ?

The only way I can think to achieve this is downloading these assets, rename them in shell, delete previous assets, re-upload them.
But this seems very tricky.

Answer (score -1):

Add a step to rename the file:

```
- name: Rename output file
    if: state == "release"   
    run: mv "/build/my-assets-rc.jar "/build/my-assets.jar"
```